# Would and will in one sentence

Tags: tense, will-would

I write a blog. In one article I am creating a tutorial. I am using a sentence with words *will* and *would*. I am not sure if the tenses are used well. The sentence is this

> Then we will add some error handling so some warnings would be expected during runtime.

The English language has some tense dependencies and I am not sure when do they work.

*update*
I must specify that the conditional is actually adding some error handling. If it is added the warning might be shown when a crash happens. In another case, when no error handling is added, the crash would be invisible and the programmer could not see what kind of errors took place.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are trying to tell the users that they can see some warnings while running the code.

You can use "can" instead of "would" which shows the possibility of getting warnings.

Some warnings can be expected during runtime.

You can also write it as

> If error handling code is present in the program, users can see the warnings on their screen in case system fails or a crash happens.

Comment: Agreed. **Can** or **may** be expected are better fits in this context, which assumes the possibility of warnings. If you are sure that there will be warnings, then **should be** expected works best..

Comment: I have added the update to my question to precise which sentence part is conditional.

Answer (score 0):

You can write that, but it is somewhat unnatural (and use *because* in place of *so*). But the following phrasing is better:

> Since some warnings would be expected during runtime, we will add some error handling.

Basically put the conditional first, then the action if the condition is met.

Comment: I have specified what should be conditional in the sentence in the update at the bottom of the question.